# ReactJS antd DatePicker enabled only every first day of each month

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, momentjs, antd

Using the [antd/datepicker](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#header) , I'm trying to enable users to choose only first day of each month whenever `monthSelect` is `true`.

The only thing I've managed to do is to enable all the dates after `current` and that is the case when `monthSelect` is `false`.

For now, I still have problem resolving the case where `monthSelect` is `true`. I've tried to disabled `value > moment().startOf('month')`, which only enables the date before first month of current month and not the following months or previous months. How can I enable datePicker for only **first day of each month**?

```
const disabledDate = (value) => {
    if (monthSelect) return value > moment().startOf('month');
    return value < moment().startOf('day');
  }
```

```
 <DatePicker 
  disabled={disabledSettingButton || disabledSaveButton}
  disabledDate={disabledDate}
  format = 'YYYY-MM-DD'
 >
 </DatePicker>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function disabledDate(value) {    
    return value.format("YYYY-MM-DD") !== moment(value).startOf('month').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
}
```

this will only enable the first date of each month.

[image: Edit]